# Image path in css for react js project

Tags: css, reactjs

Base folder structure is 
**node_modules, public, src.**

css file in public folder **public/styles.css**
images are in **src/images/icon.png**

what should be the ***correct image path*** for this image for any class in css file which kept in public folder in localhost 
eg: .icon { background: url(../src/images/icon.png) no-repeat left top;

images can see directly from http://localhost:3000/exampleimage.png if I have images in public folder.

Please help

Answer (score 2):

This file path points to a file in the images folder located at the root of the current web

```
.icon { background: url(/src/images/icon.png) no-repeat left top;}
```

This file path points to a file in the images folder located in the current folder.

```
.icon { background: url(src/images/icon.png) no-repeat left top;}
```

This file path points to a file in the images folder located in the folder one level above the current folder.

```
.icon { background: url(../src/images/icon.png) no-repeat left top;}
```

Comment: do you have any live link..?

Comment: Sorry. I don;t have any public link

Comment: when I copied image to public folder its working as per this path.
public/styles.css
public/icon.png
.icon { background: url(icon.png) no-repeat left top;}

Comment: some times image name with different test case dose not support. so please check the name.

Answer (score 1):

Your server only serve files within public folder. So that, you have to put files into public folder. In that case, you can use either ./imagefilename.jpg or /imagefilename.jpg to get the file.